# Left join a table on a collection query

Tags: magento-1, collection, query

I am doing the following to get some orders out of the system for export:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', $statusToExport)
    ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $this->processingStoreId)
    ->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', array('gteq' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastSyncTime)));
```

I need to add something in where it **doesn't** export if the order `entity_id` is in a custom table I have. If I was using SQL, I would do:

```
left join myTable as mt on main_table.entity_id = mt.entity_id
where mt.entity_id is null
```

But I am not sure how to modify the collection query to do a similar thing.

Note: I did try

```
$orders = $orders->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array("t1" => $myTable),
        "main_table.entity_id = t1.entity_id",
        array("admin_field_id" => "t1.id")
    )
    ->where("t1.id is null")
```

but this changes it so it's a query and I want the sales/order collection returned.

I feel I am missing something simple ...

**EDIT**

Ok, I have tried this:

```
$orders->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array("t1" => $myTable),
        "main_table.entity_id = t1.entity_id",
        array("admin_field_id" => "t1.id")
    )
    ->where("t1.id is null");
```

When I echo `(string)$orders->getSelect()` it returns the query I would expect and returns no results when I run it. `$orders` however, still contains items. I thought this join was meant to modify the collection at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for this.

I wanted a count of values **before** I applied the left join so I added

```
$totalOrderCount = count($orders);
```

this however caused the collection to load which in turn meant it ignored the left join I was doing further on. Whilst debugging, looking at the var `_isCollectionLoaded` was a good tip by Fabian.

I am now doing this instead to get the count of the collection:

```
$countOrdersObjs = clone $orders;
$totalOrderCount = count($countOrdersObjs);
unset($countOrdersObjs);
```

This allows me to count the results without loading `$orders` collection.

Note: Please apply any upvotes to Fabians post above as he guided me on this but I felt the solution warranted it's own answer.

Answer (score 54):

To change the query you can do

```
$collection->getSelect()->doWhateverYouWantWithSelectObject();
foreach($collection as $order) {} // order collection
```

But to join a table, you can just use `$collection->joinTable()`

`joinTable` only exists on Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection, this means: products, categories, orders, invoices, creditmemo, shipping, customers. (Thanks @Fra for the comment)

## joinTable()

But magento collections have a method `joinTable()` it took me 45min to fizzle out how it is used. To avoid this for you, I share it.

```
$productCollection->joinTable(
    array('bonus' => 'mycompany/bonus'), 'product_id=entity_id',
    array('bonus_id' => 'bonus_id')
);
```

The parameters are:

```
public function joinTable($table, $bind, $fields = null, $cond = null, $joinType = 'inner')
```

1. Table is easy, it is the magento `namespace/entity` format, which you use in your configuration, resource models and the collection. You can use an array of the format `array('alias' => 'namespace/entity')`
2. Bind means, the ON statement in your SQL. This was the hardest part and I will explain it in details later. **It is important to have your flat table BEFORE and your EAV table AFTER the equal sign.** Don't use `main_table.` before the attribute. Magento will do this for you. More on this later.
3. Fields is an **array**. If you use a string instead, you get this: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/magento-1.6.2.0/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 775`. You can use an array of the format `array('field1', 'field2', '...')` or `array('alias' => 'field1', '...')`
4. Condition is a ** <del>WHERE</del> ON condition** in the SQL.
5. joinType. I hope you know what it is. **But you have only the choice between LEFT and INNER**. `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php:793`

[More on this topic](http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/joining-a-flat-table-on-eav/)

Comment: Thanks for that great info. Based on your first point, shouldn't `$orders->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(array("t1" => $myTable), "main_table.entity_id = t1.entity_id", array("admin_field_id" => "t1.id"))
                ->where("t1.id is null")` exclude the items from my current list?

Comment: I think you edit the collection after loading. just hook into your script with xdebug and check the isLoaded flag inside the model

Comment: worth to mention that joinTable method is only available for Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection