# Sorting and filtering not working with custom column in Customer Grid Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, filter, sorting

I have add a custom column in customer grid by copying core **Grid.php** file to local folder. I want to show **last order date** of customer in a column. So I have tried below code in collection.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('track_device')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('inchoo_socialconnect_fid')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('inchoo_socialconnect_gid')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');


       // add last_order_date column     
            $sql ='SELECT MAX(o.created_at)'
                . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
                . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ';
            $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')'); 

            $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('last_order_date'=>$expr));


        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

here is the column code--

```
$this->addColumn('last_order_date', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Order Date'),
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'last_order_date',
            'filter'    => true,
            'sortable'  => true ,               
            'gmtoffset' => true,        
        ));
```

column showing correct values but **Sorting** and **Filtering** not working for this column. What is wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

Since `last_order_date` is a real field you will need to implement `filter_condition_callback`

```
$this->addColumn('last_order_date',
        array(
            ....
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterLastOrderDate'),
    ));
```

See [Magento - custom column in AdminHtml product grid which contains custom output/logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485525/magento-custom-column-in-adminhtml-product-grid-which-contains-custom-output-l)

Comment: is `last_order_date` exist in any table by default. I don't know  about this if it is exist already.

Comment: I am getting main problem in sorting this column. i don't know how to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you can not use a join / group by?

Comment: I don't know where to apply join/group in above code.

Comment: can you provide some idea.?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10359/left-join-a-table-on-a-collection-query ... you will need a `group by` customer id