# How to add column for total orders in customer grid in magento and filter it?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I am trying to add a total orders of particular customer column in customer grid. It is added successfully but How can I filter it?

Code is :

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

        $sql ='SELECT COUNT(*)'
        . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
        . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id GROUP BY e.entity_id';
        $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')'); 

        $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('orders_count'=>$expr));
        echo $collection->getSelect();die;
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {   

        if ($column->getId() == 'orders_count') {

            if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                return $this;
            }
            if (!empty($value)) {
                $from = $value['from'];
                $to = $value['to'];           
                $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
                     "orders_count >= $from AND orders_count <= $to");
            }        
            return $this;

        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;
    } 
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total Orders'),
            'align'     => 'left',
            'width'     => '40px',
            'index'     => 'orders_count',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'sortable' => true,
        ));
...}
```

Comment: Check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21313/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-filter

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102957/sorting-and-filtering-not-working-with-custom-column-in-customer-grid-magento

you might have such problems

Comment: can you add your code in questions?

Comment: @Abdul I have add my code in question. Kindly check it

Comment: @Magento2Learner I had checked both links you had mentioned but problem is filter not working because of orders_count is not a column

Comment: You can refer to answer here. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162910/2443

Comment: @JaiminSutariya, It's Working fine bro.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

IN prepare column add your column as below

```
    $this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total Orders'),
        'align'     => 'left',
        'width'     => '40px',
        'index'     => 'orders_count',
        'type'  => 'number',
        'sortable' => true,
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'yourMethodName'),
    ));
```

after `_prepareColumns` method create another method name as `yourMethodName` just like below

```
protected function yourMethodName($collection, $column)
{
if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
    return $this;
}
// your code for filter 
//$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("shipping_name like ?", "%$value%");

return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is easy and working :)

Override Grid

1. Move file **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php**
   to **app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php**
2. Add to method following code, before **$this->setCollection($collection);**
   Will add order data, orders filtering by Status - Complete

   ```
   /**
    *
    */
   $readAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
   $select = $readAdapter->select()
       ->from('sales_flat_order_grid')
       ->where('status=?', 'complete')
       ->columns(array(
               'orders_total' => new Zend_Db_Expr('CEIL(SUM(grand_total))'),
               'orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')
           )
       )->group('customer_id');
   $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
       array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $select . ')')),
       'e.entity_id = orders_count.customer_id',
       array('orders_count.orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_total')
   );
   $collection->addFilterToMap('orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_count');
   $collection->addFilterToMap('orders_total', 'orders_count.orders_total');
   /**
    *
    */
   ```
3. Add columns - in method **_prepareColumns**, add following code

   ```
   $this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
       'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total No. of Orders'),
       'align'     => 'left',
       'width'     => '40px',
       'index'     => 'orders_count',
       'type'  => 'number',
       'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_ordersCountFilterCallBack'),
       'sortable' => true,
   ));


   $this->addColumn('orders_total', array(
       'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total Sum. of Orders'),
       'align'     => 'left',
       'width'     => '40px',
       'index'     => 'orders_total',
       'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_ordersTotalFilterCallBack'),
       'sortable' => true,
       'type'              => 'currency',
       'currency_code'     => 'UAH',
   ));
   ```
4. Add 2 methods for filter callback

protected function _ordersCountFilterCallBack($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }

```
    if (!isset($value['from'])) {
        $value['from'] = '';
    }

    if (!isset($value['to'])) {
        $value['to'] = '';
    }

    $from = ($value['from']) ? $value['from'] : 0;
    $to = ($value['to']) ? $value['to'] : 999999;
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->where("orders_count.orders_count >= $from AND  orders_count.orders_count <= $to");
    return $this;
}

protected function _ordersTotalFilterCallBack($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (!isset($value['from'])) {
        $value['from'] = '';
    }

    if (!isset($value['to'])) {
        $value['to'] = '';
    }

    $from = ($value['from']) ? $value['from'] : 0;
    $to = ($value['to']) ? $value['to'] : 999999;
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->where("orders_count.orders_total >= $from AND  orders_count.orders_total <= $to");
    return $this;
}
```

5. Add fix for Sort functional

protected function _setCollectionOrder($column)
    {
        if (!$dir = $column->getDir()) {
            return $this;
        }

```
    if ($column->getIndex() == 'orders_count') {
        $collection = $this->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->order("orders_count " . strtoupper($column->getDir()));
        return $this;
    }

    if ($column->getIndex() == 'orders_total') {
        $collection = $this->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->order("orders_total " . strtoupper($column->getDir()));
        return $this;
    }

    return parent::_setCollectionOrder($column);
}
```

And will appears 2 new columns with total count orders of customer, and total sum orders of customer.